# React-native: rendering view before fetching data from Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I am trying to render *Signin* component if user not logged in and if user logged in I am trying to render *Home* component. On *Signin* component set Storage *'isLIn'* to *'true'* On *Signout* [from home component] set Storage *'isLIn'* to *'false'* and Every time React-Native App opens checking Storage and Setting State as value of Storage.

Please look at code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './login_component';
import Home from './home_component';

var KEY = 'isLIn';

export default class main extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }

  _loadInitialState = async () => {
    try {
        let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (value !== null && value === 'true') {
          this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:AsyncStorage:', error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const _isIn = (this.state.isLoggedIn===true) ? true : false;
    return (
        <Router>
          <Scene key="root" hideNavBar hideTabBar>
            <Scene key="Signin" component={Login} title="Signin" initial={!_isIn} />
            <Scene key="Home" component={Home} title="Home" initial={_isIn}/>
          </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know why but view render first before Storage gets value. According to lifecycle of react-native **render()** execute only after **componentWillMount()**  as [React_Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#mounting)  says.

I am using [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) to get set and remove Storage and also using [React-Native-Router-Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#documentation) for routing.

I have tried solutions:

- [forceUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)
- [Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553112/react-native-asyncstorage-fetches-data-after-rendering)

Comment: You can create a loading scene as the initial scene have have it check there and route based on whether it finds the user or not.

Comment: A very simple **example** of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929679/react-fetch-data-in-server-before-render/50551453#50551453

Answer (score 2):

Since what you are doing is asynchronous you can not tell the lifecycle to wait for it. But React provides states and these you can use e.g.

```
state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
    isLoading: true
  };
```

And set the state in the async

```
_loadInitialState = async () => {
    try {
        let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (value !== null && value === 'true') {
          this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true, isLoading: false });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false, isLoading: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:AsyncStorage:', error.message);
    }
  };
```

And then in your render method you can place a placeholder until your asynctask is finished

```
render() {
 if(this.state.isLoading) return <div> Loading... </div>
 else return...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it remains in Loading... view even after getting storage data and setState login to true and loading to false....
It will be best if u send me snippet of code...

Answer (score 0):

Invoking setState in componentWillMount does NOT trigger a re-rendering. `componentWillMount` runs after state has been set and before the view has been re-rendered. From React Native Docs:

"componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method." - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Instead, you should call `_loadInitialState` in `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: Sorry I don't know why but componentWillReceiveProps() never called in my code.....
Please If u Make snippet it will be best..thanks

Comment: You can call it yourself.