# retrieve data from asyncStorage in react native

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, react-native

I know the similar question has been asked such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553112/react-native-asyncstorage-fetches-data-after-rendering), but am not able to find an answer to this. I am a newbie to react-native as well. I need to retrieve data from storage this is how I store the value after API call

```
_storeData = async response => {
 it AsyncStorage.setItem(token, (response))
  .then(() => {
  this.setState({
     shouldLoad : false
   });  
    console.log("Data saved successfully" + response);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("There was an error saving the data");
  });
 };
```

This is how I tried to retrieve data from **AsyncStorage**

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem(token).then((token) => {
  this.setState({
    token : tokentoken,
    currentState : false
  });
});
```

What am trying to achieve is session management. On login, I save the sessionToken to AsyncStorage, and when the app is started again, I need to retrieve the data back. I tried different code but am not getting output.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1.**

Am pasting the whole code here so that anyone could point out where am going wrong.

```
export default class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  token: null,
  currentState : true,
};
}

 componentDidMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem(token).then((token) => {
  this.setState({
    token : tokentoken,
    currentState : false
  });
});
  }


  render() {
var ggg = this.state.token;
console.log(ggg);

if(this.state.currentState === false){

if (this.state.token === "" || this.state.token === null) {
  return <LoginNav />;
} else {
  return <HomeNavigatorNew />;
}

}

 else{
return (  <ActivityIndicator  
  animating={true}
    style={{ 
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',

      height: 80
    }}
    size="large"
  />)
  }
  }
 }
```

**EDIT 2.**

I was writing the above code in App.js I just moved the whole code to Login.js(another file) and it just worked. Does that mean anything.. .? Is it like that I should write retreiving code in App.js

**EDIT 3.**
Thanks to @Mohammed Ashfaq and @Samer Murad for responding so quickly. 
In Sammrs code I noticed the AsyncStorage is imported in  curly parenthes not without them. I was importing without them. I had mentioned in my EDIT 2 that the code was working in another file in which the AsyncStorage is impoted in curly paranthes. Leaving the modified working code for future reference for someone

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
 import   {AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator} from "react-native";
 import { createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";

 export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
  token: null,
  currentState: true,
};
 }
  _retrieveData = async () => {
   console.log("Data retrieved successfully");

 // var tokenRetrieved = AsyncStorage.getItem('LoginTocken');
await AsyncStorage.getItem('LoginTocken')
  .then(value => { 
    return (value);
  })
  .then ( valueJson => {
    this.setState({
      token : valueJson,
      currentState : false
    });
    console.log("Data retrieved successfully", valueJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("There was an error retrieving the data" + error);
  });



  };

  handleSession = async () => {
console.log("handleSession");
   this._retrieveData().catch((error) => {console.log("error is " + 
 error);});
  };

  componentWillMount() {
console.log("componentWillMount");
this.handleSession();
  }


  render() {


if (this.state.token === "" || this.state.token === null) {
  return <LoginNav / > ;
} else {
  return <HomeNavigatorNew / > ;
}
 }

}
```

I don't have a clue why and how it make difference when some import are done without curly parenthes**{}** where some are done with them. If anyone know why the curly paranthes are omitted/added at times I request them to leave a answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a LocalStorage wrapper I wrote not so long ago, It also includes the functionality to set TTL on an object/key if you need an expiration date behavior, I use it for the same logic as you do, which is to check if there is a saved token and navigate to the main app view instead of the login page.

Here is the wrapper:

```
// RN < 0.59
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
// RN > 0.59
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


/**
 *
 * @param key Key value of the object to be saved
 * @param object The Object to save
 * @param ttl (Optional) set an expiration date on an object in ms
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
export const setObjectForKey = async ({key, object, ttl = undefined }) => {

    if (!key) throw new Error('Cannot set an object without a key');

    if (!object) throw new Error('Cannot set a key without an object');

    let expiresAt = undefined;
    if (ttl) {
        expiresAt = new Date().getTime() + ttl;
    }
    let wrappedObj = {
        object,
        expiresAt,
    };
    let stringedWrapper = JSON.stringify(wrappedObj);

    return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key,stringedWrapper)
};


/**
 *
 * @param key The key of the object to remove
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
export const removeObjectForKey = async (key) => {
    return await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key)
};


/**
 *
 * @param key The key of the object to retrieve
 * @return {Promise<*>}
 */
export const getObjectForKey = async (key) => {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let stringedWrapper = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);

    if (!stringedWrapper) throw new Error('No key found for object');

    let wrapper = JSON.parse(stringedWrapper);
    if (wrapper.expiresAt < now) {
        // Object expired
        AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
        throw new Error('Object expired');
    } else {
        return wrapper.object;
    }
};
```

And here is a usage example (in my solution I have a redux middleware so after I retrieve an object I call dispatch):

**GET:**

```
let key = 'APP_TOKEN';
localstorage.getObjectForKey(key)
            .then((retrievedObject) => {
               // Do what you want with object
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               // Handle error, Object either doesn't exist, expired or a system error
            })
```

**SET:**

```
 let key = 'APP_TOKEN';
 let object = {token: 'JWT_HASH'};
 let ttl = undefinded // TTL is optional
 localstorage.setObjectForKey({
            key,
            object,
            ttl,
        })
            .then(() => {
               // Set was successfull
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Handle Error
            })
```

**DELETE:**

```
localstorage.removeObjectForKey(key)
            .then(() => {
              // Successfully deleted
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               // Object either doesn't exist to delete or system error
            })
```

Notice that I actually save objects that I stringify, so even if I'm save the api token, I actaully save an object with a token as a key, i.e: `{token: 'TOKEN'}`

Hope that helps

## UPDATE 2019-06-06

As of `react-native` `0.59`, the AsyncStorage module is deprecated due to the efforts to make `react-native`'s core library thinner... the AsyncStorage should now be installed through [@react-native-community/react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage)

Answer (score 2):

```js
 /* Login Screen */

async storeSessionToken(token) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
    console.log("Data saved successfully");
    // Rest of your code
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while storing the token");
  }
}




/* Splash Screen  */ 

async retrieveSessionToken() {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token !== null) {
      console.log("Session token",token );
      return token;
    }
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error while storing the token");
   }
}



// calling retrieveSessionToken
componentDidMount() {
  this.retrieveSessionToken()
  .then((token)=> { 
    if(token) this.setState({token: token})
  })
}
```